Should we say 'some of the ones' instead of 'some of ones'?
I have not found the second on the internet. Should we only use the first phrase? Context is: the human is choosing goods in the shop and the seller asks about what items the person wants to buy and gives to the buyer chance to point by hand these goods.

Please give some context. Guessing will not get us anywhere.

A full sentence is needed. Saying that, I find it extremely difficult to come up with an example where the second phrase sounds natural.

Someone is choosing goods… "a human" sounds quite odd and the beginning of a sci-fi story. You don't need to add "hand" when the verb point at literally means to identify or select something using your finger.

If you don't know the difference between human and person you may not know that person is far more common when talking about someone in an everyday situation (although you could say customer if it's a shop); human is mostly used to differentiate homo sapiens from other species, or in specific phrases like human rights.

Also, we'd say "the chance to point these goods out by hand" rather than delaying the direct object.

The OP's scenario is inside a shop

…gives to the buyer chance to point by hand these goods.

“I'll have some of those” would be my choice.
The buyer is pointing at some items that are further away.
Use “these” for things that are in such proximity you don't need to stretch your arm out to point at them.
If the only difference between the items being chosen are, for example, colours then you can use "ones".

"I'll have the blue and red ones"

Maybe the client is in a pet shop:

I'll have some of the ones [fish] in that tank over there"


Conversation between a fruit seller and a buyer:
Assume a fruit shop. The buyer can make his purchase in the following ways:

Without Naming, Just Pointing

The buyer can simply point to various items and use phrases like "some of these" or "some of those" to refer to the items.
Buyer: [points to a pile of fruit] "I’d like some of these, please.".
[The buyer then points to another section].
Buyer: "And some of those as well."
Here, "these" and "those" stand in for specific items, making it clear without naming them.

Using Adjectives

When the buyer specifies items with adjectives, it highlights certain qualities of the fruit.
Buyer: "I’d like some of the green apples, please.".
Buyer: "And maybe some of the ripe mangoes, too.".
Buyer: "I’ll also take some of the rotten oranges for the musical concert."
In each case, the buyer uses "some of the" followed by an adjective and the fruit name to refer to a specific selection.

Using Product Names or Origins

If the fruit has a specific origin or variety, the buyer and seller can refer to it by name.
Buyer: "Could I have some New Zealand apples?".
Buyer: "And some oranges from Greece, if you have them."
If there is only one type of apple available in the shop:
Buyer: "I’ll take some apples, please."
Here, "some [product name or origin]" works well to specify the desired type without "the" when there’s no choice or variety needed.
